# How to make the css affect the new content loaded by jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have an external css file, and now I load a table into my html page, how could the css file affect the newly loaded content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new contents appended by jquery (or prepended, or added in general) are affected by any css already present in the DOM.

Did you try it before asking?

Comment: do you add this new element in the right place, with the correct classes and using the same structure? Sometimes it's just as simple as you may be appending the table one element above or so. Could you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the code and hand it to us, plase?

Comment: sorry, my bad... forget to add <thead>

Comment: great to know. Then you could accept my answer, so newcomers can fast know which answer worked to you =)

Answer (score 0):

you need pre-styling like design that part which is shown by jquery first and hide it then show on which ever event you want.

```
.div
{
display:none;
border:2px solid #fff;
background-color:red;
height:100px;
width:200px;
}
```